# Codeigniter Email not sending in particular case

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a function to send emails

the strange thing is that its working for a particular case and not for the other

here is the debugger log

SUCCESS

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

From: "Reset Password" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "sender@email.com" 
X-Sender: sender@email.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <xxx@email.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Password_Reset?= ......
```

FAILED

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail<br /><pre>
 From: "Registration" <sender@email.com>
Return-Path: <sender@email.com>
Reply-To: "sender@email.com" <sender@email.com>
X-Sender: sender@email.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <xxx@email.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Confirm_Registration?= .....
```

see in the failed one I got the sender email repeated in some places and also it is set in reply-path which is not in the email sent successfully. Also there r some HTML tags are in it no idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this problem in my project i am not sure whether it works for you or not check your To email address is valid or not.